# svg element not working fine in cordova app

Tags: cordova, svg, mobile, cordova-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

My app is working fine on any server and even in webstorm and displaying a gauge meter but when I am running it in cordova its giving me following error in script.js file "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
    at script.js:14 ", [errorbrowser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55aQN.png)
[ERROR SCRIPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS5XJ.png)
Given below theses are the file created and being modified.
Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
          <script src="js/script.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Geo Location</title>
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map-canvas { height: 100% }
#floating-panel {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 100px;
z-index: 5;
background-color: #555;
padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
border: 5px solid rgb(200,200,200);
}
#floating-panel select{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', onSuccess);
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { timeout: 30000 });
function onSuccess(position) {
var lat=position.coords.latitude;
var lng=position.coords.longitude;

//Google Maps
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
var mapOptions = {zoom: 4,center: myLatlng};
console.log(document.getElementById('map-canvas'));
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({draggable:true,
animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP,
position: myLatlng,map: map});
}


function onError(error) {
alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
function changeLocation () {
// Get the address information from the ‘value’ of the selected item
var latlng = document.getElementById("address").value;
var lat = parseFloat(latlng.substring(0,7));
var lng = parseFloat(latlng.substring(8,15)) * (-1);
console.log(lat);
console.log(lng);
// Google Maps
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
var mapOptions = {zoom: 4, center: myLatlng};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatlng,map: map});
}
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=rochester,%20ny&appid=a7018b4326269d29fbf2e11c8dc9696a";

/* Create an XMLHttpRequest object to reqest data from a web server */  
/* (the name of the request class has the legacy 'XML...' ) */
/* because it first read only XML data                      */
var httpObj = new XMLHttpRequest();

/* This function is called every time the status of the request object changes */
/* When the readystate is 4, and the status is 200, the response is ready */
/* (in other words, information is back from the server) */
httpObj.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpObj.readyState == 4 && httpObj.status == 200) {
        /* read the response into the variable 'myArr' */
        var myArr = JSON.parse(httpObj.responseText);
        /* process the data you received from the response */
        myFunction(myArr.weather);
    }
};

/* the open method specifies the type of http request  */
/*  --- we want to use GET (not POST),                 */
/*  --- we send the name of the file to get            */
/*  --- we use 'true' for an asynchronous request      */
httpObj.open("GET", url, true);
/* the send method with no parameters is used for GET  */
httpObj.send();
/*-----------------------------------------------------*/

/* function that processes the data received from the response */
function myFunction(arr) {
    /* create a variable to hold an html string */
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /* construct each line of html from the data in your JSON file */
        out +=  
            "<div class='responsive'<div class='gallery'> " +
          //  "<img class='pic' height='200' width='300' src=images/" + arr[i].pic + ".png />" +//
            "<div class='desc'  >" + arr[i].description + "</div>" +
            "</div></div>" 
            ;
            }
    /* send the html out to the div with the ID 'listofitems' */        
    document.getElementById("listofitems").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

        <div class="container A">
            <svg class="typeRange" height="165" width="330" view-box="0 0 330 165">

                <g class="scale" stroke="red"></g>

                <path class="outline" d="" />
                <path class="fill" d="" />
                <polygon class="needle" points="220,10 300,210 220,250 140,210" />
            </svg>
            <div class="output">18</div>
        </div>

        <p>You may change the initial value by dragging over the gauge
            <br>or by editing the input below:</p>
        <input type="text" class="initialValue" value="18" />





<div class="cardlist">
    <div class="content">
        <div id="listofitems">
      <!-- The Script below gets the data into this div -->      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="floating-panel">
<!-- Create a select tag with the id='address', -->
<!-- then create several options of locations of your choice -->
<select id="address" onchange="changeLocation();">
<option value="43.1610:77.6109">Rochester NY</option>
<option value="40.7128:74.0060">New York NY</option>
<option value="41.8781:87.6298">Chicago IL</option>
<option value="Miami FL">Miami FL</option>
<option value="Los Angeles CA">Los Angeles CA</option>
<option value="Atlanta GA">Atlanta GA</option>
</select>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var containersRy = document.querySelector(".container");
var svg = document.querySelector(".typeRange");
var output = document.querySelector(".output");
var outline = document.querySelector(".outline");
var fill = document.querySelector(".fill");
var center = document.querySelector(".center");
var needle = document.querySelector(".needle");

var initialValue = document.querySelector(".initialValue");

var rad = Math.PI / 180;
var NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

var s= window.getComputedStyle(svg, null)
var W = parseInt(s.getPropertyValue("width"));
var offset = 40;
var cx = ~~(W / 2);
var cy = 160;

var r1 = cx - offset;
var delta = ~~(r1 / 4);

var initVal = initialValue.value;

var isDragging = false;

var x1 = cx + r1,
    y1 = cy;
var r2 = r1 - delta;

var x2 = offset,
    y2 = cy;
var x3 = x1 - delta,
    y3 = cy;

function drawScale() {
    sr1 = r1 + 5;
    sr2 = r2 - 5;
    srT = r1 + 20;
    var scale = document.querySelector(".scale");
    clearRect(scale);
    var n = 0;
    for (var sa = -180; sa <= 0; sa += 18) {
        var sx1 = cx + sr1 * Math.cos(sa * rad);
        var sy1 = cy + sr1 * Math.sin(sa * rad);
        var sx2 = cx + sr2 * Math.cos(sa * rad);
        var sy2 = cy + sr2 * Math.sin(sa * rad);
        var sxT = cx + srT * Math.cos(sa * rad);
        var syT = cy + srT * Math.sin(sa * rad);

        var scaleLine = document.createElementNS(NS, "line");
        var scaleLineObj = {
            class: "scale",
            x1: sx1,
            y1: sy1,
            x2: sx2,
            y2: sy2
        };
        setSVGAttributes(scaleLine, scaleLineObj);

        scale.appendChild(scaleLine);

        var scaleText = document.createElementNS(NS, "text");
        var scaleTextObj = {
            class: "scale",
            x: sxT,
            y: syT,
        };
        setSVGAttributes(scaleText, scaleTextObj);
        scaleText.textContent = n * 10;
        scale.appendChild(scaleText);

        n++

    }

}

function drawInput(cx, cy, r1, offset, delta, a) {

    var d1 = getD1(cx, cy, r1, offset, delta);
    var d2 = getD2(cx, cy, r1, offset, delta, a);

    drawScale();

    outline.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d1);
    fill.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d2);

    drawNeedle(cx, cy, r1, a);
}

function updateInput(p, cx, cy, r1, offset, delta) {

    var x = p.x;
    var y = p.y;
    var lx = cx - x;
    var ly = cy - y;

    var a = Math.atan2(ly, lx) / rad - 180;

    drawInput(cx, cy, r1, offset, delta, a);
    output.innerHTML = Math.round((a + 180) / 1.8);
    initialValue.value = Math.round((a + 180) / 1.8);
}

function getD1(cx, cy, r1, offset, delta) {

    var x1 = cx + r1,
        y1 = cy;
    var x2 = offset,
        y2 = cy;
    var r2 = r1 - delta;
    var x3 = x1 - delta,
        y3 = cy;
    var d1 =
        "M " + x1 + ", " + y1 + " A" + r1 + "," + r1 + " 0 0 0 " + x2 + "," + y2 + " H" + (offset + delta) + " A" + r2 + "," + r2 + " 0 0 1 " + x3 + "," + y3 + " z";
    return d1;
}

function getD2(cx, cy, r1, offset, delta, a) {
    a *= rad;
    var r2 = r1 - delta;
    var x4 = cx + r1 * Math.cos(a);
    var y4 = cy + r1 * Math.sin(a);
    var x5 = cx + r2 * Math.cos(a);
    var y5 = cy + r2 * Math.sin(a);

    var d2 =
        "M " + x4 + ", " + y4 + " A" + r1 + "," + r1 + " 0 0 0 " + x2 + "," + y2 + " H" + (offset + delta) + " A" + r2 + "," + r2 + " 0 0 1 " + x5 + "," + y5 + " z";
    return d2;
}

function drawNeedle(cx, cy, r1, a) {

    var nx1 = cx + 5 * Math.cos((a - 90) * rad);
    var ny1 = cy + 5 * Math.sin((a - 90) * rad);

    var nx2 = cx + (r1 + 15) * Math.cos(a * rad);
    var ny2 = cy + (r1 + 15) * Math.sin(a * rad);

    var nx3 = cx + 5 * Math.cos((a + 90) * rad);
    var ny3 = cy + 5 * Math.sin((a + 90) * rad);

    var points = nx1 + "," + ny1 + " " + nx2 + "," + ny2 + " " + nx3 + "," + ny3;
    needle.setAttributeNS(null, "points", points);
}

// helpers
function oMousePos(elmt, evt) {
    var ClientRect = elmt.getBoundingClientRect();
    return { //obj
        x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
        y: Math.min(Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top), cy)
    }
}

function clearRect(node) {
    while (node.firstChild) {
        node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
    }
}

function setSVGAttributes(elmt, oAtt) {
    for (var prop in oAtt) {
        elmt.setAttributeNS(null, prop, oAtt[prop]);
    }
}

// events
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var pa = (initVal * 1.8) - 180;
    var p = {};
    p.x = cx + r1 * Math.cos(pa * rad);
    p.y = cy + r1 * Math.sin(pa * rad);
    updateInput(p, cx, cy, r1, offset, delta)
}, false);

initialValue.addEventListener("input", function() {
    var val = this.value;
    var newVal = (!isNaN(val) && val >= 0 && val <= 100) ? val : 18;
    var pa = (newVal * 1.8) - 180;
    var p = {};
    p.x = cx + r1 * Math.cos(pa * rad);
    p.y = cy + r1 * Math.sin(pa * rad);
    updateInput(p, cx, cy, r1, offset, delta)
}, false);

svg.addEventListener("mousedown", function(evt) {
    isDragging = true;
    this.classList.add("focusable");
    var mousePos = oMousePos(svg, evt);
    updateInput(mousePos, cx, cy, r1, offset, delta);
}, false);
svg.addEventListener("mouseup", function(evt) {
    isDragging = false;
    this.classList.remove("focusable");
}, false);
svg.addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt) {
    isDragging = false;
    this.classList.remove("focusable");
}, false);

svg.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
    if (isDragging) {
        var mousePos = oMousePos(svg, evt);
        updateInput(mousePos, cx, cy, r1, offset, delta);
    }
}, false);
```

style.css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: #0a1a17;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #ccc;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px auto 50px auto;
    height: 165px;
    width: 330px;
}

.output {
    line-height: 35px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #0f4534;
    border-radius: 60px 60px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 135px;
    left: 135px;
    text-align: center;
}

.initialValue {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #399988;
    color: #399988;
    display: block;
    width: 3em;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 1em auto;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}
/*SVG*/

svg {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #0a1a17;
}

svg.focusable {
    border: 1px solid #0f4534;
}

.outline,
.fill,
.center,
.needle,
.scale,
.output {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.outline {
    fill: #0f4534;
}

.fill {
    fill: #399988;
}

.needle {
    fill: #aa0000;
}

.scale {
    stroke: #aaa;
}

text {
    text-anchor: middle;
    dominant-baseline: alphabetic;
    font: 12px verdana, sans-serif;
    fill: #aaa;
}
```

Apart from these I didn't make any changes in the Index.js and Index.css file which is generated by default in cordova.